# MongoDB query on an index field and another unindexed field

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb, indexing, mongoose

Each document in my user collection has 2 fields: `email` (**uniquely indexed**), and `password` (not index).

So, if I do something like `model.findOne({ email: "john@gmail.com", password: "abc" });`, will MongoDB search the entire collection to see which document match the email and password provided? Or MongoDB will be smart, and only binary search in the indexed space, aka check if each indexed document has the password provided.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use model.findOne(...).explain() to get your answer via nscannedObjects in result

Comment: Why would you even want to check for the password value? Why check for the value of ANY property other than the uniquely indexed one, for that matter? 
While I understand your curiosity about the inner workings of MongoDB, it hardly matters in your current example- just fetch the document with the unique email, and then make other checks in your `exec` function.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic Say instead of find, you do an atomic update with the same query.

Comment: @user1561559 I see, sounds legit. I tried googling, as I'm sure you have as well, but it seems impossible to know without looking at the source. I suspect they implemented some sort of lazy evaluation, where they'd first check if the query contains a unique index, try and find matches, and then try and match the rest of the query.